# determine request time out in angular $http

Tags: angularjs

I am sending an http request using angular as below.

```
$http({
    url: url,
    params: params,
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    timeout: 60000    //60 seconds
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //do something 
}).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
    if(timedout){  //determine occurrence of timeout.
        //invoke timeout handler
    } else  
        //handle other error
    }
});
```

How can I determine the timeout?

I have observed that status code "0" is received in this case. Is it safe to check status==0 for timeout?

Please note that I am not asking about HTTP Request timeout (status code 408).

Comment: All I know is that `status === 0` does **not** symbolise a timeout. It's the code used when the server doesn't respond with a correct HTTP status, or doesn't respond at all.

Comment: It's also the status when a call is aborted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have done it as below...

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
$http.post(...)
    .success(function(resp, status, header, config) {...})
    .error(function(resp, status, header, config) {
        var respTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        if(respTime >= config.timeout){
            //time out handeling
        } else{
            //other error hanndling
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice workaround, but would checking for data == null and status == 0 not improve for the case that we get an error just before the timeout and then checking in javaScript respTime would be >= config.timeout?

if (data == null && status == 0 && respTime >= config.timeout)

Comment: Now, in later anuglarJs, I believe we can use `xhrStatus` field of response. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns.

Answer (score 6):

I just read through the source code. In the source code of the [$httpBackend](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L96), the `xhr.ontimeout` is not being handled. They should implement `xhr.ontimeout`.

Unfortunately Angularjs doesn't support the http timeout handling for right now. :(

Comment: angular does support http timeout, the problem is to distinguish timeout to other network-related errors.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage), the `timeout` parameter is expressed in milliseconds.

So you're setting it at 1 milliseconds, which is extremely low. This will probably make the request fail in 99.9999 % of situations.